# When is the sum of coprime pairs coprime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I'm curious about the following elementary question.

Suppose that $a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2$ are integers such that $\mathrm{gcd}(a_1,b_1)=\mathrm{gcd}(a_2,b_2)=1$ and either $a_1\neq a_2$ or $b_1\neq b_2$ (or both).

> **Question:** Assume in addition that $\mathrm{gcd}(a_1+a_2,b_1+b_2)=1$ holds.
>
> What does this imply for the integers $a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2$?

In particular, do they have to satisfy the following relation $a_1b_2-a_2b_1=\pm 1$ (or a similar relation)?
Edit: There are simple counterexamples to this (as in the comment by Mr.Brooks), so this relation does not necessarily hold.

Thanks for any help, references are also much appreciated.

**Note:** I've edited the original question, which was: *When is $\mathrm{gcd}(a_1+a_2,b_1+b_2)=1$?*.

Comment: It's hard, in general, to mix additive and multiplicative properties.  I wouldn't expect a very useful answer to this...though of course one can find many cases in which the sums are not coprime.  for instance, if  all four are odd, the sums can't be relatively prime.  Or if $a_1,a_2$ are even and $b_1,b_2$ are odd.

Comment: About the prime factors of $a+b$ that are not already in *both* $a$ and $b$, you can say that they are in *none* of them, and that's about all you can say. It's unpredictable. Which is why the $abc$ conjecture is an incredibly hard statement to prove.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I've just edited the question, perhaps it is more tractable now.

Comment: Have you looked at examples?

Comment: Okay, let's try $\gcd(3, 5) = \gcd(4, 7) = 1$. Then also $\gcd(7, 12) = 1$ still. And $3 \times 7 - 5 \times 4 = 21 - 20 = 1$. Hmm, the very first bunch of numbers I picked...  let's try instead $\gcd(3, 7) = \gcd(4, 11) = 1$. Then also $\gcd(7, 18) = 1$ still. But $3 \times 11 - 7 \times 4 = 5$.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, clearly I should have looked at more examples. But perhaps there are other relations that one could deduce.